# Cardboard boxes on AeroMexico

Tags: luggage, aeromexico

I am going from San Jose Costa Rica to Mexico City for a few days.  I want to buy some talavera tiles and planters.

Will I be able to ship them as checked baggage in a cardboard box with Aeromexico? I know Jetblue does not allow cardboard boxes, but not sure about other airlines and can't find anything on AeroMexico's website.

Answer (score 3):

Aeromexico states at the bottom of their [baggage information](https://aeromexico.com/en-us/travel-information/baggage) page that boxes or coolers are allowed as long as they are seal-wrapped.

> **Baggage Wrapping Services**
>
> "Secure Wrap" services can be found at select airports. This service is designed to protect your baggage for a low fee.
>
> **Boxes and Coolers**
>
> Secure Wrap is required for passengers traveling with boxes or coolers. Items may not be wrapped together as a single unit, each item must be individually wrapped.

Comment: Welcome to TSE and thank you for your contribution; however, please transcribe text rather than relying on screenshots. Screenshots are useless to people using screen readers or translation software, and they are not indexed by search engines, so other people with the same problem will have a harder time finding the answer. At the very least, you should provide a link to the original source.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the only mention of cardboard boxes in the context of luggage that I can find on Aeroméxico's website is talking about transporting chickens on internal flights. (For internal flights, cardboard boxes are ok; for international flights, chickens have to be in wooden boxes).

Google also finds a [comment on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/interjet.mx/posts/10152487611933441) by someone who says (my translation from Spanish):

> On Aeroméxico I brought as checked luggage a box the size of a suitcase without any problem. They only asked me not to label it as food (so a Guadalupe Eggs box wouldn't do lol), sealed with sellotape, and weighing no more than about 50lbs.

It's not clear whether that was an internal flight or an international one.

I would reckon that if it's within the normal size and weight restrictions and you get it wrapped by one of those people with plastic wrap machines (which they definitely have in Benito Juárez, because I've had my backpack wrapped there in the past) then you shouldn't have any problems, but if you want a definitive answer you'll have to phone Aeroméxico's customer support.

You might want to consider, though, whether it would be preferable to transport pottery in a hard-sided suitcase. Luggage gets thrown around a bit, and I know that when my parents bought some tiles in Spain and took them back to the UK in hold luggage, well wrapped, one of them arrived cracked from side to side.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I sent email to Aeromarine a week ago, no response. I have tried calling also, but the people I speak with, have no idea!